# Change Bundle level in felix?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I know how to set an initial bundle level, for just to be deployed bundle:

```
bundlelevel -i 5
```

But how do I change the level of an existing bundle? Help for bundlelevel says:

```
  bundlelevel - set bundle start level or initial bundle start level
   scope: felix
   flags:
      -i, --setinitial   set the initial bundle start level
      -s, --setlevel   set the bundle's start level
   parameters:
      int   target level
      Bundle[]   target identifiers

bundlelevel - query bundle start level
   scope: felix
   parameters:
      Bundle   bundle to query
```

I have no idea what "Bundle[]" argument is. I tried just bundle_id and [bundle_id], and even bundle name.

Let me show an example. Let's say I want to change bundle 5 (bookshelf api) level from 1 to 2.

```
g! lb
START LEVEL 5
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (3.0.7)
    1|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (1.6.2)
    2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.6.1)
    3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.6.1)
    4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.6.1)
    5|Active     |    1|Bookshelf Inventory API (1.5.0)
```

I tried the following:

```
g! bundlelevel -s 2 [5]
gogo: IllegalArgumentException: Cannot coerce 
    bundlelevel(String, String, ArrayList) to any of 
    [(boolean, boolean, int, Bundle[]), (Bundle)] 

g! bundlelevel -s 2 5
Must specify target bundles.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some experience in FUSE ESB but never used felix.
Just downloaded felix 3.0.8 and tried:

```
g! lb
START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (3.0.8)
    1|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (1.6.2)
    2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.8.0)
    3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.8.0)
    4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.8.0)

g! bundlelevel -s 10 4

g! lb
START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (3.0.8)
    1|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (1.6.2)
    2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.8.0)
    3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.8.0)
    4|Resolved   |   10|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.8.0)
g!
```

I tried hard to reproduce your problem but could not. It seams to work as specified. Did you tried it in a fresh installation or with a newer felix version (do not know what you are using)?

Answer (score 1):

Not the clearest of syntax messages I guess :) Bundle[] refers to bundle IDs. Do lb, get the ID for the bundle you want, then run

> bundlelevel -s NEW_LEVEL BUNDLE_ID

e.g.: for level 4 and bundle 10, do

> bundlelevel -s 4 10

Maybe you were getting complaints because you missed the -s?

Comment: Nope, that still does not work. If I have a bundle with id=5, and level=1, and I want to change it to level 2 and do: "bundlelevel -s 2 5" the felix says "Must specify target bundles".