# Oracle Java EE First Cup Tutorial 2.1--GlassFish 3.1.2 Errors

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm pretty familiar with Java SE and am just starting to learn Java EE and doing the First Cup Tutorial. I followed all of the instructions carefully. I am running this on my work computer (Windows 7) with a work firewall (Windows Firewall).

When I attempt to launch the GlassFish server I get this output in NetBeans:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
INFO: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
INFO: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 9ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:3700]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 19ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:4848]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 51ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 33ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 2ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:7676]
INFO: The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.
INFO: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
INFO: SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service
INFO: SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-2] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [admin-listener] on host/port [0.0.0.0:4848]
INFO: WEB0171: Created virtual server [server]
INFO: WEB0171: Created virtual server [__asadmin]
INFO: WEB0172: Virtual server [server] loaded default web module []
INFO: Registering the Jersey servlet application, named org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig, at the servlet mapping, /resources/*, with the Application class of the same name
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [dukes-age] at [/DukesAgeService]
INFO: CORE10010: Loading application dukes-age done in 2,585 ms
INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (5) startup time : Felix (1,388ms), startup services(3,239ms), total(4,627ms)
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
INFO: Created EjbThreadPoolExecutor with thread-core-pool-size 16 thread-max-pool-size 32 thread-keep-alive-seconds 60 thread-queue-capacity 2147483647 allow-core-thread-timeout false 
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 3ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.11.1 03/31/2012 06:49 PM'
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-2] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 2ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]
INFO: REST00001: Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain
INFO: The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.
INFO: The Admin Console is starting. Please wait.
**SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [__admingui]
SEVERE: Failed to start Bundle Id [336]  State [INSTALLED]   [org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin(Glassfish OSGI Console Plugin):3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
com.sun.enterprise.module.ResolveError: Failed to start Bundle Id [336]  State [INSTALLED]   [org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin(Glassfish OSGI Console Plugin):3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.start(OSGiModuleImpl.java:177)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$2$1$1.loadClass(OSGiModuleImpl.java:344)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.LazyInhabitant.loadClass(LazyInhabitant.java:124)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.LazyInhabitant.fetch(LazyInhabitant.java:111)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:135)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ClassLoaderHierarchyImpl.createApplicationParentCL(ClassLoaderHierarchyImpl.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:216)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createDeploymentClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:346)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Cannot start bundle org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin [336] because its start level is 2, which is greater than the framework's start level of 1.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1807)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.start(OSGiModuleImpl.java:169)
    ... 12 more

SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [__admingui]
INFO: The Admin Console application is loaded.
INFO: JMX005: JMXStartupService had Started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://MW7FVCH7MQLSJX.dir.svc.accenture.com:8686/jndi/rmi://MW7FVCH7M**QLSJX.dir.svc.accenture.com:8686/jmxrmi
INFO: Registered org.glassfish.osgi.felixwebconsoleextension.GlassFishBrandingPlugin@591e1b
INFO: defaultVirtualServer = server
INFO: No default web.xml
INFO: standardContext = StandardEngine[glassfish-web].StandardHost[server].StandardContext[/osgi]
INFO: No default web.xml
INFO: standardContext = StandardEngine[glassfish-web].StandardHost[__asadmin].StandardContext[/osgi]
```

The output lines that begin with "SEVERE:" look pretty bad. But then again, I'm a Java EE newbie.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate caused by in the stack you posted says:

```
Cannot start bundle org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin [336] because its start level is 2, which is greater than the framework's start level of 1.
```

You may want to do some research on the start level of the framework.  Check out:
[How is the OSGi bundle start level defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462259/how-is-the-osgi-bundle-start-level-defined) or https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-2942.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a GlassFish JIRA issue on this with a workaround:

http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18880