# How to configure user bundles so that they can be autostarted with higher priority - hence earlier than others?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, equinox

I need to run certain plugins before others. First thought was to add names of bundles, priorities in '\configuration\bundles.info' but on start of OSGI it was throwing error `java.lang.Exception: Could not find plugin com.example.myplugin`.
The added line was similar to this:
`com.example.myplugin,1.1.1,dropins/MY-ARTIFACT-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/eclipse/plugins/com.example.myplugin-1.1.0.SNAPSHOT.jar,2,true`

Then I added  to `\configuration\config.ini` the parameter:

```
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\com.example.myplugin-1.1.0.SNAPSHOT.jar@2\:start
```

Same error persisted. How to solve it?

Comment: I think that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462259/how-is-the-osgi-bundle-start-level-defined) should cover your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right. Start level in OSGi is defined by the @2 you put in your `config.ini` file. The default (by default) is a start level of 4.
It seems that your problem is more related to a directory path problem to access the bundle rather than the load order of your bundles themselves.