# Creating JAAS Configuration Using Java in Felix OSGI

Tags: apache-felix, sling

I want to set a default JAAS configuration in Apache Sling for a SAML2 sign on bundle (not using the `/system/console/configMgr` UI)

```
jaas.classname="org.apache.sling.auth.saml2.sp.Saml2LoginModule"
jaas.controlFlag="Sufficient"
jaas.ranking=110
jaas.realmName="jackrabbit.oak"
```

I am considering two options:
A) Creating a "config" node in a JCR Filevault package under /apps
B) Creating the configuration using Java in a bundle's activate method

**Approach A** works OK upon package install. It does set the configuration I want, but upon restart Sling is not happy, and never completes start up. There is an error in the logs shown below. I interpret this as some kind of timing conflict as bundle mentioned in the JAAS config which provides the LoginModule is not activated yet. (Feel free to post your thoughts about that)

Approach A ERROR upon restart...

> 27.06.2020 14:28:45.985 *ERROR* [Apache Sling Resource Provider Change Notifier] org.apache.sling.extensions.threaddump.internal.Activator Uncaught exception in Thread Thread[Apache Sling Resource Provider Change Notifier,5,main]
> java.lang.AssertionError: No bundle exists to create LoginModule from org.apache.sling.auth.saml2.sp.Saml2LoginModule
> at org.apache.felix.jaas.internal.BundleLoginModuleCreator.newInstance(BundleLoginModuleCreator.java:59) [org.apache.felix.jaas:1.0.2]
> at org.apache.felix.jaas.internal.ConfigLoginModuleProvider.createLoginModule(ConfigLoginModuleProvider.java:80) [org.apache.felix.jaas:1.0.2]
> at org.apache.felix.jaas.boot.ProxyLoginModule.initialize(ProxyLoginModule.java:46) [org.apache.felix.jaas:1.0.2]
> at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:716)
> at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:665)
> at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:663)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:663)
> at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:574)
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.core.ContentRepositoryImpl.login(ContentRepositoryImpl.java:163) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-core:1.26.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.repository.RepositoryImpl.login(RepositoryImpl.java:282) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-jcr:1.26.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.repository.RepositoryImpl.login(RepositoryImpl.java:225) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-jcr:1.26.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl.impersonate(SessionImpl.java:275) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-jcr:1.26.0]
> at org.apache.sling.jcr.oak.server.internal.TcclWrappingJackrabbitSession.impersonate(TcclWrappingJackrabbitSession.java:84) [org.apache.sling.jcr.oak.server:1.2.4]
> at org.apache.sling.jcr.base.AbstractSlingRepository2.createServiceSession(AbstractSlingRepository2.java:205) [org.apache.sling.jcr.base:3.1.0]
> at org.apache.sling.jcr.base.AbstractSlingRepository2.createServiceSession(AbstractSlingRepository2.java:170) [org.apache.sling.jcr.base:3.1.0]
> at org.apache.sling.jcr.base.AbstractSlingRepository2.loginService(AbstractSlingRepository2.java:383) [org.apache.sling.jcr.base:3.1.0]
> at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrProviderStateFactory.createProviderState(JcrProviderStateFactory.java:115) [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.20]
> at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.authenticate(JcrResourceProvider.java:303) [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.20]
> at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.authenticate(JcrResourceProvider.java:75) [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.20]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.providers.stateful.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:161) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.providers.stateful.ProviderManager.getOrCreateProvider(ProviderManager.java:87) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.providers.stateful.ProviderManager.authenticateAll(ProviderManager.java:129) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.createControl(ResourceResolverImpl.java:143) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.(ResourceResolverImpl.java:104) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.(ResourceResolverImpl.java:98) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.CommonResourceResolverFactoryImpl.getResourceResolverInternal(CommonResourceResolverFactoryImpl.java:280) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverFactoryImpl.getServiceResourceResolver(ResourceResolverFactoryImpl.java:89) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.JcrResourceBundleProvider.createResourceResolver(JcrResourceBundleProvider.java:163) [org.apache.sling.i18n:2.5.14]
> at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.JcrResourceBundleProvider.onChange(JcrResourceBundleProvider.java:266) [org.apache.sling.i18n:2.5.14]
> at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.JcrResourceBundleProvider.onChange(JcrResourceBundleProvider.java:216) [org.apache.sling.i18n:2.5.14]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.observation.BasicObservationReporter.reportChanges(BasicObservationReporter.java:211) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.observation.BasicObservationReporter.reportChanges(BasicObservationReporter.java:189) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.providers.ResourceProviderTracker.postResourceProviderChange(ResourceProviderTracker.java:406) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.providers.ResourceProviderTracker.access$400(ResourceProviderTracker.java:59) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.providers.ResourceProviderTracker$2.run(ResourceProviderTracker.java:517) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.16]
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

With **Approach B** I don't think I there will be this race condition or timing issue, and it should be possible to write a configuration using the Java code below.

```
    void createSaml2Jaas(){
        logger.info("create saml2 jaas");
        try {
            Configuration jaasConfig = configAdmin.createFactoryConfiguration(JAAS_SAML2PID);
            Dictionary<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<>();
            properties.put("jaas.classname", "org.apache.sling.auth.saml2.sp.Saml2LoginModule");
            properties.put("jaas.controlFlag", "Sufficient");
            properties.put("jaas.ranking","110");
            properties.put("jaas.realmName","jackrabbit.oak");
            jaasConfig.update(properties);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Problem creating JAAS Configs", e);
        }
    }
```

This creates an OSGI config, but it is not bound properly. The config as shown in the Web Console states the following

> This form is automatically generated from existing properties because no property descriptors are available for this configuration. This may be cause by the absence of the OSGi Metatype Service or the absence of a MetaType descriptor for this configuration.

[image]

**Question:** What do I need to do to create an `org.apache.felix.jaas.Configuration.factory` OSGI Config programmatically (or via a package) that is properly bound without causing problems with application startup?

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, my 'problem' is a little different than the exact 'question' posted. With regard to the question, I would still like to know how to write Felix OSGI configurations for a bundle using Java code.

There is a solution in this post
[How is the OSGi bundle start level defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462259/how-is-the-osgi-bundle-start-level-defined) about setting the bundle startup value. Apache Sling JCR Installer (org.apache.sling.installer.provider.jcr) is the bundle responsible for creating OSGI configurations from definitions in JCR nodes under '/apps' under 'runmode/config' This bundle has a Start Level of 20.

Changing the start level of my bundle from 20 to 19. Resolved the Java exception printed in the error.log

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

private static final int START_LEVEL = 19;

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    context.getBundle().adapt(BundleStartLevel.class).setStartLevel(START_LEVEL);
```